# Detecting coordinates in monocolor image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to find out the coordinates of the white area (for the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSZJd.png) ) in the black background in order to crop it. I want to crop all these white areas separately. Therefore, I was approaching as a contour to these shapes but it does not work. At the same time, I approached it as an object but also it does not. Consequently, how I must approach these white areas in order to detect and crop?

````
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

bw = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(bw,127,255,0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


cntx1 = contours[0][0]
cntx = contours[0][1]

pt1 = (cntx1[0][0],cntx1[0][1])
pt2 = (cntx[0][0],cntx[0][1])

cv2.circle(img,pt1,5,(0,255,0),-1)
cv2.circle(img,pt2, 5, (0,255,0),-1)

cv2.imshow('f',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() ```
````

Comment: How many white areas are you expecting to detect and crop? I'm assuming you're trying to crop the large regions so 7? Adding an expected output image for the desired regions to crop can help

Comment: It can be change depends on input but in one case it is 6 btw I found 400 areas with code but it is not working. I need more efficient code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `cv2.bitwise_not` then `cv2.add`. Because I don't have your source image so I made one.

```
img = cv2.imread("flower.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

bit_not = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
bit_not_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(bit_not, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

res = cv2.add(bit_not_bgr,img)

cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
cv2.imshow("bit_not",bit_not_bgr)
cv2.imshow("res",res)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can differentiate colors picture to b/w but the problem is detecting these areas. I don't know how tho find and show in a rectangle with coordinates. The general case is find out areas of questions in an image and crop them separately to read them in ocr.